# why big float number in javascript turns into zero?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
Math.pow(3, -222)
```

***gives 1.199724291183359e-106***

```
 5 + Math.pow(3, -222)
```

***gives 5 !***

i have tried to use parseFloat() and also toPrecision() but nothing happened

Comment: Floating point numbers have limited ability to represent very large and very small values.

Comment: `1.199724291183359e-106` is a *very small* number, not a "big" one.

Comment: because`5 + Math.pow(3, -222)` simply can't be presented by one number..

Comment: @LiadYogev It is not only a question of representing, small parts are just lost, if you will reduce 5 it will show you 0, not an original value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I suggest that you peruse https://floating-point-gui.de/ which is a very gentle introduction into functioning of floating-point numbers, and their limitations.

Comment: @DmitryReutov if it can't be represented as a number, how can you expect it to save it as a number?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem there is anything "wrong" with the math used here, but if your float is so small JavaScript can not handle it properly, you may want to rework you project. I can't imagine any use case in which you couldn't just use a larger decimal.

Comment: @LiadYogev, data and view are different things, you can not say that something is impossible to keep in data, just make 1000000 size array for each digit and keep incomparable more small numbers than this

Answer (score 3):

This is because IEEE floats are very precise close to zero. The farther away from zero you get, the less precise you can be.

3^-222 is so small that, when added to 5, it is rounded down to zero.

5+3^-222 doesn't exist as a float, and is closer to 5 than it is the smallest number above 5, so it's rounded down to 5.